# Modify groups attribute name value being sent over in Azure assertion?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, manifest, assertion

I've enabled the groups configuration in the manifest to send over the UID values pertaining to the groups the user has, but the name is passed with the default URI

Is there a way to modify that value so it's just "groups"?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change resource group names in AAD. You can move your resources into a new resource group.